# understanding while loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I am quite new to *Python* and trying to learn algorithms, I wanted to ask why is it logically wrong if I use `low < hi` when looking over the list, the correct logical operation is `low <= hi`, what is the edge case it is preventing.

```
def binary_search(input_array, value):
    """Your code goes here."""
    #O(log(n))
    low = 0
    hi = len(input_array) - 1 
    while low <= hi: #why cant it be low < hi
        mid = (low + hi)//2
        if input_array[mid] == value:
            return mid
        elif input_array[mid] < value:
            print(low, hi)
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            hi = mid - 1
    return -1


test_list = [1,3,9,11,15,19,29]
test_val1 = 25
test_val2 = 15
print(binary_search(test_list, test_val1))
print(binary_search(test_list, test_val2))
```

Comment: Consider editing the question and appending the raised exception you're encountering. Guessing games are harshly down-voted here :D

Comment: @Juggernaut - No guessing game here.  He's not getting an exception, he's asking about the logic of the algorithm.  As the answers point out, if you change the logic you don't get an exception but you get something much worse: the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your target is, for example in your case, 15:

1st iteration indexes: `low == 4`, `hi == 6`

2nd iteration indexes: `low == 4`, `hi == 4`

If you use low < high you won't drop into your loop on the second iteration, since 4 < 4 returns `false`. Your program will think it can't find the value even though the value is on index 4.

Answer (score 5):

Consider you have only one element `[1]` and you are searching for `1`.

`<`  : return `-1` Since you would just skip the loop

`<=` : return the correct value

Answer (score 0):

We use `<=` instead of just `<` because in the case that the desired value happens to be the last index (when `low=hi`), we will need to include an equal sign to check for that case.

Answer (score 0):

You could **if** you had written
    
    `hi = len(input_array)

    while low < hi:     # now this works.

    ...`

In fact generally this it's how I generally write these loops. Take advantage of the fact that `len()` will always be 1 more than the last index, and run the loop only while the index is `<` that value.

If you subtract 1 from the `len(input_array)` so that the max value for `hi` *is* the last index in the array, then in order to ruin the loop on that last element you need the `=` part of `low <= hi`

Generally it's (mentally) easier to instead set `hi = len(input_array)`, which is 1 past the last index, and then run the loop only while `low<hi` .
(Less typing, and less mental gymnastics).
In this case, once `low==hi` we've gone past the last index, and it would then be out of bounds.

The "edge case" you refer to is that you want to make sure to run the loop on **all** elements (indexes).
So one way or another, you need to look at that last index/element out the array.

Basically there are two common ways to code this, but you cannot mix them up. Make sure your end condition is with respect to your initial condition.

What you set `hi` to (either the length of the array, or the last index of the array) determines whether you are going to use `low < hi` or `low <= hi`